# Can I throw exception in a for loop , if memory exceeds in that loop

Tags: php

How can I handle an exception happening in a foreach loop?

I want to throw my exception if the for loop didn't work properly.

As data is huge, foreach exits because PHP's memory limit is exceeded.

```
try
{
 foreach()
}catch (exception $e)

{
echo $e;
}
```

This is not working. How do I throw an exception?

Comment: Could you paste some more code? As it stands, all I see are syntax errors. Also, what do you mean by not working?

Comment: why dont you understand that is a dummy code??

Comment: @zod Your dummy code is useless, and might as well have been omitted. You could at least have done `foreach() { /* memory limit exceeded here */ }`

Comment: Thats right .But try to understand the question first.See and learn what the other guys are answered and commented.

Comment: @zod You're in no position to judge other people's understanding.

Comment: some people understand nothing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory exceeded is a fatal error, not an exception and cannot be handled with try/catch blocks.
What you need is [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

EDIT: If that does not work you can use [register_shutdown_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) as a last resort and check if the script was stopped by and error.

Comment: Fatal errors (such as memory being exceeded) are not captured by user land error handlers.  So there is no way to capture said error.  The only way would be to check the memory usage prior to it being exceeded...

Comment: thanks ircmaxell  and Alin Purcaru to lead me into right way.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what happens inside your loop, you can use the [`memory_get_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) function. This will not fix any memory related issues, but at least you can prevent PHP from exiting due to exceeding the memory_limit. Example:

```
try{
   $memory_limit = 1*1024*1024; /* 1M, this should be lower than memory_limit */
   foreach($something as $anything){
      if(memory_get_usage() >= $memory_limit){
          throw new Exception('Memory limit exceeded!');
      }
   }
}
catch(Exception $ex){
   //handle error, optionally freeing memory by unset()-ing unused variables
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible. memory exceed is a fatal unrecoverable error. so the page should be terminated when any of this happen.

But I found this question for catch E_ERROR : [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)